# How to annotate my bean with a namespace without the prefix ns2 ? JAVA

Tags: xml, xsd, tags, schema

I have a bean named School which has variables student,teacher,classroom. How do I annotate my bean so that I get the correct namespace in XML without the prefix ns2. I need to validate the xml formed with the appropriate XSDs.

1. I don't want to implement package level schema to remove the prefix since I have other beans with different namespace which fall under the same package.
2. If I annotate with `@XmlRootElement(name = "School", namespace="http://www.example.org/one")` I get the ns2 prefix.

Please guide me with an implementation which results in the xml below

```
<School xmlns="http://www.example.org/one">
<Student>Raj</Student>
<Teacher>Max</Teacher>
<Classroom>B1</Classroom>
</School>
```

Comment: Just a note that validation against XML schema is not dependent on the actual namespace prefixes, so that cannot be the reason.

Comment: I get ns2 prefixed to both the namespace and root tag. My XSD is failing to validate if the root tag has a prefix !

Comment: Can you show us the XSD?